# increase maximum byte size of nodejs pipe

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven, stream

I'm trying to write a little commander script that proxies to other scripts in my project and I'm trying to use node to pipe the stdout from the spawned process to the current process's stdout:

```
function runCommand(command, arguments) {
    var commandProcess = childProcess.spawn(command, arguments);
    commandProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    commandProcess.on("exit", process.exit);
}
```

this works fine until I start getting large output from my sub processes (for example one of them is a maven command). What I'm seeing is that it only prints out the first 8192 bytes of the stdout and then stores the rest until the next "data" event. Then it prints out the next 8192 etc. That means there's a lag in the output and at times when we're running a server process sometimes it stops printing things out until you trigger something on the server that triggers another "data" event.

Is there a way to increase the size of this buffer or avoid this behavior? Ideally this commander script just proxies to our other scripts and should print out everything exactly as is.

Answer (score 1):

You are using node process spawn which is asynchronously asynchronous so it will give output as an when the child process gives stdout.
Ref: [https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options][1]

I recommend to use child process exec to run your process where you can control the size of output buffer, which will give output after the child process is finished.This is how you pass buffer size

```
var execute = function(command, callback){
    exec(command, {maxBuffer: 1024 * 500}, function(error, stdout, stderr){ callback(error, stdout); });
};
```

Comment: thanks! I'll see if that works for what I need. The reason I didn't try it at first was because of the amount of data being printed to `stdout`. Ideally I'd like buffer size to be 'infinite' and for it to just print out what is output, I thought this is what `.pipe` would do.

Comment: actually we can't use `exec`, since this is a server command (ie. a process that doesn't exit until you tell it to manually) we actually want this to be asynchronously asyncronous. It looks to me like the `spawned` process has a hardcoded limit of 8192 bytes and I need a way around this.